# How to use prepare/execute pdo with LIKE and OR?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this pdo query:

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT ... WHERE `tags` LIKE '$keywords %' OR `tags` LIKE '% $keywords %' OR `tags` LIKE '% $keywords'");
```

and I want to convert it to prepare/execute pdo. I have wrote:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT ... WHERE `tags` LIKE ? OR `tags` LIKE ? OR `tags` LIKE ?");
$stmt->execute(array('$keywords %', '% $keywords %', '% $keywords'));
```

but it doesn't work. How should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have incorrect syntax. Putting variable in `''` will turn it into a string. Put only `%` in `''` and add it with `.` to your executed variable. The following should work:

**Example:**

```
$stmt->execute(array($keywords . '%', '%' . $keywords . '%', '%' . $keywords));
```

Comment: Thanks, I get it. Another way is $stmt->execute(array("$keywords %", "% $keywords %", "%$keywords"));
i.e. to change single quotes to double if I use double in my statement, it works too